# C/C++: Is there a specific reason why "void" was not simply defined as "typedef struct{} void" (i.e. an empty struct) with appropriate casting rules?

Tags: c, syntactic-sugar

As an aside: Such a standard **typedef** would have help reduce the number of *reserved words* in C/C++, and relegated **void** to a simple  **type** declaration, e.g. in [<stddef.h>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stddef.h#stddef.h). (c.f. [SRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) in [AB33/Mar 1972](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/ACM_Algol_bulletin/1061601/p54-bourne.pdf) - PDF=7kB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty speculative. But one good reason is because `void` is not an empty value; it's the absence of a value. For instance, a function with a signature of `int f(void)` takes zero arguments, not one.

Comment: The syntax `int f(void)` came long after `void` was invented, as did stddef.h . The question is far outside of what is a appropriate at SO and should not be answered (but not being Richard Snoot III, I won't downvote it).